# How to convert a Java Collection/List to a Scala seq?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to instantiate a Kafka Scala case class from Java code, and it has the following signature:

```
case class OffsetFetchRequest(groupId: String,
                          requestInfo: Seq[TopicAndPartition],
                          versionId: Short = OffsetFetchRequest.CurrentVersion,
                          correlationId: Int = 0,
                          clientId: String = OffsetFetchRequest.DefaultClientId)
```

I'm able to send all the requested parameters, except for the `Seq[TopicAndPartition]`.

On the Java side, I have the following code:

```
OffsetFetchRequest offsetFetchRequest = new OffsetFetchRequest(
                                                "someGroup", 
                                                topicAndPartitions, 
                                                (short)1, 
                                                1, 
                                                "clientId");
```

As expected, a `java.util.List`is not compatible with a Scala `Seq`.  However, I've tried all types of conversion methods in `JavaConversions` and `JavaConverters`, and I can't find anything that fits this case.

How can I create a Scala `seq` from a normal `java.util.List` or even a `java.util.Collection`?  Or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: What about `toList` or any other of the `Seq` subtype converters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer` which would convert Java list to Scala buffer, of which toList method can be used to convert to immutable seq.

Alternative, you could use `CyclicIterator` as well.

Comment: Thanks!  Calling `.asScalaBuffer().toSeq` did the trick for me.